# Installing Primefaces on Domino Application Server

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces, xpages, lotus-domino

Domino currently uses XPages.  It is a JSF View Controller that uses Dojo and/or Bootstrap/JQuery as the rendered UI from its server side UI Components.  The IDE is eclipse, and there is a eclipse view with all the controls you can drag onto the page (design view and code xml view)

Example:

```
f:javax.faces.Component
   f:javax.faces.Output
      f:javax.faces.Input
         xp:com.ibm.xsp.UIInputEx
            xp:com.ibm.xsp.UIInputText
               xp:inputText
```

https://www.openntf.org/xspext/xpages%20extension%20library%20documentation.nsf/xpages-doc/xp_inputText.html

The server and eclipse both have jsf 1.1 installed, and tightly coupled configuration with the server.

How can I install Primefaces so the server can render out the Primefaces UI https://www.primefaces.org/manhattan/dashboard.xhtml

1. Install JSF 2 (how)
2. Install Primefaces (use JBoss install instructions?)
3. Install the UI components into Eclipse
4. Uses Ant for building, do I need to change anything there?

Server is running Domino Java 8.

Another tip, I think the server run time and libraries are loaded using OSGi.

Comment: Do you want to use Primefaces components in a XPage, or run Primefaces on top of Domino? I have Vaadin and Spring applications which are deployed as OSGi plugins, so Primefaces should also run on Domino too.

Comment: Hi Sven, do you have a blog or reference for how to wrap these frameworks in a OSGi plugin and deploy to the server?  I thought of using Primefaces on its own, however, not a bad idea to mix it in with XPages either (didn't think of doing it this way).  Where do I start?

Comment: I found this Vaadin JSF integration project https://github.com/alejandro-du/vaadin-jsf-integration.  Unrelated to Primefaces, but I wanted to share it.

Comment: For mixing Vaadin with XPages have a look at this project https://github.com/hasselbach/VaadinInXPages